# Auto jump to a header in text

Tags: html, css

So I have a long piece of text on a webpage. What I want to do is have an inventory with links to the different headers in that text so for example when I click on "Information" it automatically jumps to the header called "Information" in the text. Can't really find how I can achieve this.

Can anyone link me, or tell me if it's short how to do this?

Comment: Not exactly sure, but are you looking for **jQuery-ScrollTo()** function. Please have a look at this article **http://balupton.github.com/jquery-scrollto/demo/** . Go to the section Using jQuery ScrollTo and click on any item !!! See that what you need

Answer (score 2):

You can use hash tags to do this.

In your text you would have headings with id's like so:

```
<h1 id="info">Information</h1>
```

Then for a link you want to jump to this section you would write:

```
<a href="#info">Go to info</a>
```

The important thing to note is the `#IDHERE` in your anchor

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose can be used `href` and `name`/`id` attributes of html tags:

```html
<h1><a href="#section1">Go to Section1</a></h1>
<h1><a href="#section2">Go to Section2</a></h1>
....
....
....
<p><a name="section1">Section1</a></p>
....
....
....
<p id="section2">Section2</p>
....
....
....
```

[Shown also here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You do it with 'a' tags.

Your link:

```
<a href="#header1">link to header number one</a>
```

Your header:

```
<a name="header1"></a>
<h1>Header Number One</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put an unique id like:

```
<a href="#info">get me to the information</a>

<p><a name="info"></a>Information</p>
```